# How to make non editable text box to editable when i click on check box corresponding to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are one check box and a non editable text box corresponding to it. When I click on check box, corresponding non editable text box should become an editable text box. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code actually works fine, and ready to use.

This is the form stuff:

```
<form id="myGame" name="myGame" action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="checkme" id="checkme" onClick="openTheHouse();" >Open Sesame
<input name="open_id" id="openid" type=text disabled="disabled">
</from>
```

And the Script: its pretty cool actually, nothing complicated in this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openTheHouse()
{

if(document.myGame.checkme.checked == true)
{
document.myGame.openid.disabled = false ;
}

}
</script>
```

thats it, all done. Certainly i believe it works.

Comment: This won't work for `openid` as its name is actually `open_id`. Also, this doesn't do the reverse. Even though not explicitly asked by the OP, I think it would make more sense if it did. The radio button should be a checkbox. So basically after all `<input type="checkbox" onclick="form.open_id.disabled=!checked">` should do.

Answer (score 4):

Basically:

```
$('#some-checkbox').click(function() {
   $('#some-textfield').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Now, how you go about finding the corresponding text box depends on your markup. One way could be to give the text box a class that is the ID of the checkbox. Applying that to all checkboxes might look something like this:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
   var box = $(this);
   $('.' + box.attr('id')).prop('disabled', !box.is(':checked'));
});
```

Otherwise, the text field may be located by its position on the DOM:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <input type="checkbox">
   ...
   <div>
      <input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
   </div>
</div>
```

You might then do something like:

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
   var box = $(this);
   box.closest('.wrapper').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', !box.is(':checked'));
});
```